# How to get the checkeditems in a listview in C#?

Tags: c#, listview

I have a list view and the user can check multiple items in the listview and the code will compare the values checked in the listview with the values in a table in MS Access database.
The problem is that if the value that checked by the user is X, it will be turned into {Text="X"} and compare this with the value in the database, which is wrong.
Does anyone have an idea of what is going on?
This is how I get the checked items:

```
foreach (Listview module in listView1.CheckedItems)
{
    if(module.ToString() == Convert.ToString((test.Tables["objects"].Rows[i]["objectname"])))
}
```

Just briefly explain how I added the items to the listview:
I have a table in my database, the items in the list view comes from one of the columns of that table. but I need my table to be sorted based on, for example, column[1] and then export the values in column[2] to the list view. I also grouped the items into three groups.

```
ListViewGroup Small_Modules = new ListViewGroup("Small Modules", HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        ListViewGroup Medium_Modules = new ListViewGroup("Midum Modules", HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        ListViewGroup Heavy_Modules = new ListViewGroup("Heavy Modules", HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        //find the maximum moment in the column
        //this maximum basically does nothing and it was just for future refrencess 
        double max_moment = 0;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        foreach (DataRow item in test.Tables["objects"].Rows)
        {
            //i is defined to count the number of modules in the table
            i++;
            //Proj_ID is a user input through a textbox
            if (proj_ID == Convert.ToInt32(item["projID"]))
            {
                if (max_moment < Convert.ToDouble(item["moment"]))
                {
                    max_moment = Convert.ToDouble(item["moment"]);
                }
            }
        }
        //sort the table based on the moment in an ascending order
        DataView dv = test.Tables["objects"].DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = "moment ASC";
        DataTable sorted_dt = dv.ToTable();

        //define each group members
        foreach (DataRow row in sorted_dt.Rows)
        {
            //First one third of the items goes into group one 
            //Second one third of the items goes into group two
            //last one third of the items goes into group three
            j++;
            //Proj_ID is a user input through a textbox
            if (proj_ID == Convert.ToInt32(row["projID"]))
            {
                if (j <= i / 3)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(Convert.ToString(row["objectname"]), Small_Modules));
                }
                else if (j <= i * 2 / 3 &&  j > i / 3)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(Convert.ToString(row["objectname"]), Medium_Modules));
                }
                else if (j > i * 2 / 3)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(Convert.ToString(row["objectname"]), Heavy_Modules));
                }
            }
        }
        listView1.Groups.Add(Small_Modules);
        listView1.Groups.Add(Medium_Modules);
        listView1.Groups.Add(Heavy_Modules);
```

I am using C#WFA
My database is MS Access

Comment: How do you add items to the listview? Can you share that code? `Listview module` should be changed to `ListviewItem module`

Comment: That was a typo, yes I am using ListviewItem. Sure I will update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am surprised that no one knows the answer to this question. I could find the answer by debugging the code line by line and check what is going on behind the scene.

When using a listview, the items will be saved as {Text = "X"}, while in the list view we have only X. In order to have access to X in my question, I had to use module.Text instead of only module.

```
foreach (Listview module in listView1.CheckedItems)
{
    if(module.Text.ToString() == Convert.ToString((test.Tables["objects"].Rows[i]["objectname"])))
}
```